# how to create two class methods and using the first class methods variables on an if statement on the other method - Java

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, class-method

So I'm trying to create a program that displays the dinosaurs era which it lived in and other stuff but I'm currently stuck on the age.

Here is the question:

> `setTimePeriod` (method) – takes one int parameter representing how many millions of years ago the dinosaur lived and does not return anything; sets the time period instance variable to the middle of the time period. See below for more information
>
> `getTimePeriod` (method) – takes no parameters; returns a String containing one of “Triassic”, “Jurassic”, or “Cretaceous”. Use the time period instance variable to figure out the time period.
> Setting the Time period
>
> Recall the Mesozoic Era, when the dinosaurs lived, is divided into three time periods
>
> Triassic (roughly 252 to 201 million years ago) 
> Jurassic (roughly 201 to 145 million years ago) 
> Cretaceous (145 to 66 million years ago)
>
> Set the instance variable for the time period to the middle of the time period.
>
> This gives the following numbers
>
> Triassic Period is set to 227 
> Jurassic Period is set to 173 
> Cretaceous Period is set to 106

here is what I wrote:

```
public String getTimePeriod()
{
    if (Triassic > 201 && Triassic < 252)
    {
        return "Triassic period";
    }
    
    if (Jurrasic > 145 && Jurrasic <201)
    {
        return "Jurrasic period";
    }
    
    if (Cretaceous > 66 && Cretaceous < 145)
    {
        return "Cretaceous period";
    }
}
// Returns a String representing which
// period the dinosuar lived in
// based on the value of the time period instance variable


// setTimePeriod

public int setTimePeriod(int age)
{
     int Triassic = 227;
     int Jurrasic = 173;
     int Cretaceous = 106;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: I suggest you learn about instance variables. Note that you only need one variable to represent the age of the dinosaur, not three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to repeat about encapsulation in Java.

All conditions of this task is hard to understand, so this is my way to solve this problem:

```
public class Dinosauros {

    private String namePeriod;

    private int timePeriod;

    public void setTimePeriod(int age) {
        if (age < 252 && age > 201) {
            this.timePeriod = 227;
        } else if (age < 201 && age > 145) {
            this.timePeriod = 173;
        } else if (age < 145 && age > 66) {
            this.timePeriod = 106;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter correct time period.");
        }
    }
    
public String getNamePeriod() {
        if (timePeriod == 227) this.namePeriod = "Triassic";
        else if (timePeriod == 173) this.namePeriod = "Jurassic";
        else if (timePeriod == 106) this.namePeriod = "Cretaceous";
        return namePeriod;
    }
}
```